# Angular ngrx/store how to add middleware that will skip action

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I'm trying to figure out how to create a middleware that will check a property from the action and based on that will decide if to drop the action or not.

In simple redux I would do it like this:

```
store => next => action => {
    if(!action.payload.someBoolean) {
        next(action);
    }
}
```

How can I do this with ngrx/store?

Comment: You might be looking for [`ngrx/effects`](https://github.com/ngrx/effects)?

Comment: @Sasxa Actually, I don't think `ngrx/effects` will help here, as the actions received by effects will have already been received by the store and run through the reducers.

Comment: Yea, you're right. Can you check before dispatching an action? Or if you're using action creators, check there (if action.evil, action.type = 'dummy')?

Comment: It seems that we are missing important functionality with ngrx/store that will work as usual with angular redux.

Comment: @Sasxa I want to create something global and not repeat myself.

Comment: With the next version of `ngrx/store`, it seems you should be able to inject your own [`ActionsSubject`](https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/master/src/actions_subject.ts#L34-L36) and could add whatever filtering middleware you wanted to, but I cannot see a way you could add something like this to the currently released version. However, I could easily be wrong.

Comment: If you feel that something important is missing, maybe you might want to [create an issue](https://github.com/ngrx/store/issues) to see what the authors have to say about this?

Comment: Thanks I will try.

Comment: Have you tried the `filter` operator? You could check if the payload qualifies a condition and only then allow it to go further.